# Unable to display a serialized image in PHP from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I've uploaded some images to a MySQL database table, using the 'serialize' function so I have the possibility to save multiple images to one location in the table. This function is working fine, however, this is now where I'm stuck as a newbie!!

I have my serialised value in my database table (shown below), and the image has been saved to my server.

```
a:1:{i:0;s:19:"1431013957.9861.JPG";}
```

This is as far as I can get. I want to display the image on the front end of the site. I can call the stored information from the table using the echo function to display the whole value as text. However, I don't need all this information, I only need part of the value - the file name... (1431013957.9861.JPG).

That way I can simply enter into some code like this to display the image:

```
<img src="img/<?php echo $config->photo_a ?>"/>
```

Is there a way to unserialize or select part to my value when I echo it so I can easily display the image saved? I've tried quite a few things and looked everywhere for an answer but can't find the solution.

Thank you for you help in advance!!

Comment: you're using it as an object, but the serialized data clearly says it's an array. `echo $config[0]`: `a:1`, (a) with one (1) entry, `i:0:s19`, index #0, containing a value which is a (s)tring of (19) characters.

Comment: Makes sense. Does this mean my method is no good for what I want to achieve? Or is there away to display or select the image(s) from the array? Thanks.

Comment: well, if your serialized value is just an array with one entry that contains a string, why store a serialized array at all? Just store the raw filename string, and save yourself the serialization overhead. beyond that, you just have to change how you're accessing the unserialized data.